# jQuery datepicker overlaps input, when weeks number is increased in calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CEBzw/)
I have input with jQuery datepicker (that opens up on focus).

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker()
```

[image]
when we choose another month, that have greater number of weeks, datepicker overlaps input.

[image]
I can always open down datepicker, and this problem will be resolved, but it's not good solution.
Do you know another solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the trick:

```
$(document).on('click','.ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker-next',function(){
    var height = $('.ui-datepicker').height();
    if(height > 245) {
        $('.ui-datepicker').css('top','20px');
    } else {
        $('.ui-datepicker').css('top','50px');
    }
});
```

So basically, this code will get the height of your `datepicker` when you click the `next` or `previous` arrow and adjust the css `top` value based on the calculated height.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CEBzw/1/)**